# Multilengual Laravel app blade navigation

Tags: php, laravel

I have laravel application, I store current language inside `locale` and  inside blade I have routes like that: `<a href="{{ url('/contact') }}">Contact</a>`. But I get error because I want for example `en/contact`, not just `/contact`. So how can I set this locale inside href?

Answer (score 3):

Your route could be `Route::get('/{locale}/contact')->name('contact')`.

You can link with `route()` helper like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('contact', ['locale' => 'en']) }}">
```

This generates the desired link.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Config::get('app.locale')`.

```
<a href="{{ url('/'.Config::get('app.locale').'/contact') }}">Contact</a>
```